# Angular 8 Load Image hosted on Contentful before view with Resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to overcome the following:

[image]

As you can see here, as the page is loaded, the view renders, then the images slowly loads. How can I make it so that the view only renders when the images has been fully loaded? Mind you the images is hosted on another domain, on Contentful.

I am trying to use the Resolve API but I am confused of its implementation because I am not making a HTTP request.

Below is my resolve service:

```js
export class GalleryImagesResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  
  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService
  ) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.contentfulService.getGalleryImages();
  }
}
```

And here the contentful service:

```js
  //get Gallery Images
  getGalleryImages(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
      // include : 2,
      content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.gallery
    }, query))
      .then(res => res.items);
  }
```

Any input is much appreciated! Maybe my whole approach is wrong so if you have better solution please enlighten me. :)

Comment: Are you using it as `<img>` or as `background-image`? If there is img tag then you can get image loaded event as `<img [src]="ImgURL" (load)="imageLoaded()">`

Comment: Seems like it could also be an image (file)size vs bandwidth issue to me. How large is the image that is being displayed in your page (pixels and KB/MB)? I seem to remember there being a way to resize/optimise images to display better through Contentful's CDN, which would definitely help improve the loading speed straight away.

Comment: Are you loading _all_ the images in one go? If you are, I would recommend looking into an approach that only loads the images you need to lazily.

Comment: What does the `cdaClient.getEntries` method return? Please show also the html template code where you bind the image.

Answer (score 0):

Like "Sangwin Gawande" mentions above, you can achieve this in the HTML with the `(load)` eventListener.

Here's a helper component which I use to achieve this:

**Child component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'img-with-loader',
  template: `

    <div *ngIf="loading">
      LOADING CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
    <img
      [hidden]="loading"
      [src]="imgSrc"
      (load)="loading = false"
    />
  `
})
export class ImgWithLoaderComponent {
  @Input()
  imgSrc: string;

  loading = true;
}
```

**Parent component**

Just use this instead of a regular `<img>` element and it will not display the image (like your question shows) until it's finished loading from the server.

```html
<!-- background won't show until the image is finished loading -->
<img-with-loader [src]="backgroundUrl"></img-with-loader>
```